# How do source from a user's python environment and perform a pip install

Tags: python, bash, pip

How do I  install Python modules as another user into that user's python environment?

I tried the following lines in a bash script but `pip install` is still running in the global python environment.

```
sudo -i -u otheruser source /home/otheruser/project/project-env/bin/activate
sudo -i -u otheruser pip install -r /home/otheruser/project/project/requirements.txt
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -i -u otheruser source
```

runs in a new shell. When the command finishes the shell exits and all changes brought by `sources` disappears. You have to run all commands in one shell:

```
sudo -i -u otheruser bash -c "
    source /home/otheruser/project/project-env/bin/activate
    pip install -r /home/otheruser/project/project/requirements.txt
"
```

You can do this simpler. To run a Python script in a virtual environment you don't need to source its activation script. Just run `python` from the virtual environment:

```
sudo -i -u otheruser /home/otheruser/project/project-env/bin/python -m pip install -r /home/otheruser/project/project/requirements.txt
```